# How to create a folder symlink that has a different name?

Tags: symlink, ln

I want to create a symlink

```
~/.pm2/logs -> /opt/myapp/log
```

When I run

```
ln -sFf /opt/myapp/log ~/.pm2/logs
```

I get a symlink

```
~/.pm2/logs/log -> /opt/myapp/log
```

which is not what I want.

I'd prefer a POSIX-compatible solution if possible.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You already have a *directory* at `~/.pm2/logs`.  Since that directory exists, the symbolic link is put inside it.

Would you want that `~/.pm2/logs` is a symbolic link rather than a directory, then you will have to remove or rename that existing directory first.

Comment: I thought "-Ff" flags are specifically made to replace target directory so I don't have to remove it manually. Am I wrong?

Comment: @ptkvsk The `-F` flag does something completely different and is not a POSIX option. The `-f` flag would not unlink a directory. The [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/ln.html) specifies that if the target (the last operand) is a directory, then the link will be place inside it. The `-f` option does not change this behaviour.

Answer (score 8):

As other answers say, there is already a directory there.

To avoid this and instead get an error-message, use the `-T` option, unfortunately I don't think this is Posix (it is GNU).

From the Gnu `ln` manual (same for cp and mv).

```
   ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME   (1st form)
   ln [OPTION]... TARGET                  (2nd form)
   ln [OPTION]... TARGET... DIRECTORY     (3rd form)
   ln [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY TARGET...  (4th form)
```

Note form 1 without the `-T` is ambiguous with form 3 (both have two arguments).

In Posix you can force this non-ambiguity by putting a `/` at the end of a directory name, in form 3, but I don't think there is any thing you can do the other way around. This is why Gnu added the `-T` option.

Comment: Thank you! I'm on Mac so can't use -T, but still good to know.

Comment: Yes you can, you just need Gnu `ln` from Gnu binutils.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the ~/.pm2/logs directory first, because your target is an existing directory, the link is created inside it.